# What is the right way to backup my whole phone?

Tags: backup, factory-reset

I did a factory reset last night, and I'd like to try to mod my G1 but I want to make sure I have a good, complete recovery image. Preferably one that will restore things like my K9 mail settings, in addition to my installed applications. If I went ahead right now with the modding I wouldn't need these things but I need to just use my phone for a few days, for which I'd like to arrange my settings.

I think I need to use nandroid, so maybe my real question is: are there caveats to be alert to in a nandroid backup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only want apps/settings backed up, I recommend [Titanium Backup](http://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup).  It requires root.  Its backup will be saved to `/mnt/sdcard/TitaniumBackup/`, you can copy that folder to your computer just in case your card gets formatted.

If you use ClockworkMod / nandroid, do the same thing (copy the `/mnt/sdcard/clockworkmod/backup` folder to your PC afterwards).  The only real caveat is that you *should* flash the ROM you had when the backup was done before restoring the backup.  If the ROM you flashed afterward was significantly different, restoring without first reflashing the previous ROM can brick the phone.

Comment: That detail about ClockworkMod is something about which I had no clue.  I'm really glad I read this before I ever needed to restore a backup from nandroid!

Comment: What would you recommend if you are wanting to do a full backup *before* rooting your device?

Comment: There's no need to return to the "old ROM" if you just want to restore single items with Titanium Backup. Just think of using the "Migration Mode", at least when it comes to system data, and stay away from restoring system apps.